# Angular2 components using Bootstrap without need for jQuery?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, jqwidget

Im looking over the documentation. Can the jqWidgets Angular2 components be used with Bootstrap but without including jQuery - similar to how the ng-Bootstrap components work?
reference - https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home

Im starting a new web app with Angular2.x and wish to pull in Bootstrap for UI layout.  My team has a license for jqWidgets which we were looking at for a project that uses a lot of jQuery.  Does a a license include only the jQuery widgets or everything – including the Angular2 components?

Looking over the examples here
http://www.jqwidgets.com/angular-components-documentation/
The references include jQuery.  Are there any plans to remove the need for jQuery?

Comment: [ngx-bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-bootstrap)

Comment: http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/